# Extract value from ValueProvider in Apache Beam

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a runtime value that I'm getting in my Apache Beam program. I need to access that value but Beam does not allow me to read that value unless I'm reading it from within a transfrom like ParDo.

If I try to access that value outside any transform, it gives me an error saying:
"Not called from a runtime context".

How to read such values?

P.S. I'm using a template of the program.

Answer (score 3):

A program (such as a template) is executed in two stages. In the first, the main method is evaluated to produce a pipeline structure. This represents the template. In the second stage, that pipeline structure is executed.

Accessing a ValueProvider during evaluation (outside of a user-defined function like a DoFn) is imposible, because the runtime values aren't provided until the second stage.

Could you elaborate on what you are trying to do? Generally, the solution is to make the ValueProvider available to the DoFn, and then have the DoFn evaluate the ValueProvider at runtime.

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve some data in Beam using BigQuery Client Libraries, but the query that I must use for it depends on my runtime value. So basically the query will look something like :
"SELECT * FROM `projectID.datasetID.tableID` WHERE col='MY_RUNTIME_VALUE'". How to achieve this?

Comment: I forgot to mention something. I need to get the result in String and not a PCollection hence didn't wanna use BigQueryIO.read(). So whatever result I would get using Client Libraries I'd return that as String. I know this might be difficult but is there any way we can achieve this?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use BigQueryIO.read(). Not doing so will lose a lot of reliability functions provided by the reader. Colud you elaborate on that?

Comment: I want to make WRITE_TRUNCATE and WRITE_APPEND configurable while writing to BigQuery. The information that I'm trying to get from BigQuery as stated in my first comment will tell me which mode to use(Truncate or Append). And I don't think I'll be able to apply the received info. as side input to BigQuery.write()..withWriteDisposition(). Hence thought of using Client Libraries.
If you feel I should do it some other way please let me know.

Comment: Unless `withWriteDisposition` takes a `ValueProvider` you won't be able to compute this at runtime. If it takes a `Boolean` you are computing that at pipeline construction time, which means it won't be called from a runtime context.

Comment: But is it possible for withWriteDisposition() to take a ValueProvider?

Comment: It [does not currently](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/f7e8f886c91ea9d0b51e00331eeb4484e2f6e000/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/BigQueryIO.java#L1031). It may be possible to change BigQueryIO -- you can file a feature request on the Beam Jira and/or look at adding it yourself.