# Read from multiple Pubsub subscriptions using ValueProvider

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I have multiple subscriptions from Cloud PubSub to read based on certain prefix pattern using Apache Beam. I extend `PTransform` class and implement `expand()` method to read from multiple subscriptions and do `Flatten` transformation to the `PCollectionList` (multiple `PCollection` on from each `subscription`). I have a problem to pass subscription prefix as `ValueProvider` into the `expand()` method, since `expand()` is called on template creation time, not when launching the job. However, if I only use 1 subscription, I can pass `ValueProvider` into `PubsubIO.readStrings().fromSubscription()`.

Here's some sample code.

```java
public class MultiPubSubIO extends PTransform<PBegin, PCollection<PubsubMessage>> {

    private ValueProvider<String> prefixPubsub;

    public MultiPubSubIO(@Nullable String name, ValueProvider<String> prefixPubsub) {
        super(name);
        this.prefixPubsub = prefixPubsub;
    }

    @Override
    public PCollection<PubsubMessage> expand(PBegin input) {
        List<String> myList = null;

        try {
            // prefixPubsub.get() will return error
            myList = PubsubHelper.getAllSubscription("projectID", prefixPubsub.get());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LogHelper.error(String.format("Error getting list of subscription : %s",e.toString()));
        }

        List<PCollection<PubsubMessage>> collectionList = new ArrayList<PCollection<PubsubMessage>>();

        if(myList != null && !myList.isEmpty()){
            for(String subs : myList){
                PCollection<PubsubMessage> pCollection = input
                        .apply("ReadPubSub", PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes().fromSubscription(this.prefixPubsub));    
                collectionList.add(pCollection);
            }

            PCollection<PubsubMessage> pubsubMessagePCollection = PCollectionList.of(collectionList)
                    .apply("FlattenPcollections", Flatten.pCollections());
            return pubsubMessagePCollection;
        } else {
            LogHelper.error(String.format("No subscription with prefix %s found", prefixPubsub));
            return null;
        }
    }

    public static MultiPubSubIO read(ValueProvider<String> prefixPubsub){
        return new MultiPubSubIO(null, prefixPubsub);
    }
}
```

So I'm thinking of how to use the same way `PubsubIO.read().fromSubscription()` to read from `ValueProvider`. Or am I missing something?

Searched links:

- [extract-value-from-valueprovider-in-apache-beam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45818059/extract-value-from-valueprovider-in-apache-beam) - Answer talked about using DoFn, while I need PTransform that receives PBegin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately this is not possible currently:

- It is not possible for the value of a `ValueProvider` to affect transform expansion - at expansion time, it is unknown; by the time it is known, the pipeline shape is already fixed.
- There is currently no transform like `PubsubIO.read()` that can accept a `PCollection` of topic names. Eventually there will be (it is enabled by [Splittable DoFn](http://s.apache.org/splittable-do-fn)), but it will take a while - nobody is working on this currently.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `MultipleReadFromPubSub` from apache beam io module https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.27.0/_modules/apache_beam/io/gcp/pubsub.html

```
topic_1 = PubSubSourceDescriptor('projects/myproject/topics/a_topic')
topic_2 = PubSubSourceDescriptor(
            'projects/myproject2/topics/b_topic',
            'my_label',
            'my_timestamp_attribute')
subscription_1 = PubSubSourceDescriptor(
            'projects/myproject/subscriptions/a_subscription')

results = pipeline | MultipleReadFromPubSub(
            [topic_1, topic_2, subscription_1])
```

Comment: do you know how you would go about writing those topics to different paths in a GCS bucket? I am just trying to do that at the moment.